# How can I submit a form in nuxt to the WordPress database?

Tags: wordpress, forms, nuxt.js

I want to manage my forms through WordPress, but these forms are in a nuxt project. Actually, there is no admin panel, I just want to use WordPress for forms and for example articles

What should I do?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You can insert your data into "the WordPress database" like you insert it in any other database